# Failed to read from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am writing a program in which I need the value from firebase, the values are getting inserted perfectly, but I'm unable to read it. Below is my method to read the data. Please suggest where am I going wrong.

```
     private void displayChatMessage()
    {

        ListView listOfMessage = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

        adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage>(MainActivity.this, ChatMessage.class, R.layout.list_item, FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()) {
            @Override
            protected void populateView(final View v, final ChatMessage model, final int position)
            {

                DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("mychatapp-409f8").child("data");

                ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                            ChatMessage model = dataSnapshot.getValue(ChatMessage.class);


                            TextView messageText, messageUser, messageTime;

                            messageText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.msg_body);
                            messageUser = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.msg_user);
                            messageTime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.msg_time);



                            messageText.setText(model.getmsgbody);
                            messageUser.setText(model.getUname());
                            messageTime.setText(DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy(hh:mm a)", model.getMtime()));


                        }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }
        };

        listOfMessage.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


And my demo class is

    public class ChatMessage
{
    public String user;
    public long mtime;
    public String msgbody;
    public String uname;


    public ChatMessage(String user, String msgbody,String name)
    {
        this.user = user;
        this.msgbody = msgbody;
        this.uname = name;

        mtime = new Date().getTime();
    }

    public String getUname() {
        return uname;
    }

    public void setUname(String uname) {
        this.uname = uname;
    }

    public ChatMessage() {
    }

    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public long getMtime() {
        return mtime;
    }

    public void setMtime(long mtime) {
        this.mtime = mtime;
    }

    public String getMsgbody() {
        return msgbody;
    }

    public void setMsgbody(String msgbody) {
        this.msgbody = msgbody;
    }

}
```

My firebase hierarchy is this:

[image]

Comment: Your implementation of `FirebaseListAdapter` is not right, in above code, you use root of your data as source while you want `/data` as source. Try init `DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("mydatabasename").child("mychild")` before adapter initialization, then place `ref` as your source, like: `new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage>(MainActivity.this, ChatMessage.class, R.layout.list_item, ref)`

Comment: @ koceeng, I updated the code, but still no luck, it is not displaying in list.

Answer (score 1):

I still need the name of layout xml file that contains `R.id.msg_body`, `R.id.msg_user`, etc. But if we consider the layout name is `R.layout.your_layout`, then your code should look like this:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("data");
adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage>(MainActivity.this, ChatMessage.class, R.layout.your_layout, ref) {
    @Override
    protected void populateView(final View v, final ChatMessage model, final int position) {
        TextView messageText, messageUser, messageTime;

        messageText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.msg_body);
        messageUser = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.msg_user);
        messageTime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.msg_time);

        messageText.setText(model.getmsgbody);
        messageUser.setText(model.getUname());
        messageTime.setText(DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy(hh:mm a)", model.getMtime()));
    }
};

listOfMessage.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Hope this helps

> Note: This is just a wild guess, I want to write it in comment because I'm not sure it will work, but I think comment field is not enough

Comment: First, i am passing the layout in FirebaseListAdpater as R.layout.list_item, which has msg_body and msg_user and msg_time textfields. Second, Can we directly add child "data", as a reference in getReference() without specifying the database name. "DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("data");".

Comment: I have added a for loop "for(DataSnapshot post : dataSnapshot.getChildren())" and rest of code in it, it is displaying in list now but only the last entry of database in each list item.

Comment: Answer to your question, first: then change `R.layout.your_layout` to `R.layout.list_item`, second: we actually can and should, because when you put your database name on it, it will call `mychatapp-409f8\mychatapp-409f8\data` (something like that). And answer to your other comment is: why you do for loop? `FirebaseListAdapter` has done it for you, please try using my sample as it is so if you encounter another error, I can understand it more easily. Regards